# Sort pandas by Date, custom aggregator: combine all the data for each date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to to find a solution how I could change my pandas dataframe.
I have a dataset with news headlines. There are multiple headlines per day. I would like to have the date(day) as rows and each headline gets assigned to a new column per day.
In other words I would like to combine all the headline data for each date. Instead of having a separate headline for each day.
Some sort of pandas custom aggregator could do the job, but I'm struggling to come up with one.

I was able to group the data by date but now all the headlines per day are in the same column. and not in separate columns. (see picture 2)

```
df_nyt_all.groupby(['date'], as_index = False).agg({'headline': ','.join})
```

I have been looking for a solution for a while now but without any luck.

I attached 3 pictures. The first picture shows what my df looked like originally.
[image: current df]

[image: current df]

The third picture shows an example how I would like the df to look like.

[image: how the df should look like]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a small dataframe as an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['d1','d1','d1','d2','d2'],'headline':['h1','h2','h3','h4','h5']})
```

we can refine your own answer as such:

```
df.groupby(['Date'], as_index = True).agg({'headline': ','.join})['headline'].str.split(',', expand=True)
```

which splits the headlines you joined by a comma into separate columns:

```
    0   1   2
Date            
d1  h1  h2  h3
d2  h4  h5  None
```

This is not very robust as if the headlines had commas it would split on those as well. A more robust solution is a variant of this, where we aggregate first by collecting headlines per date into a list, and then expand lists:

```
df.groupby('Date', as_index=True)['headline'].apply(list).apply(pd.Series).reset_index()
```

(here I reset the index -- you can do the same in the first solution) to get

```
    Date    0   1   2
0   d1      h1  h2  h3
1   d2      h4  h5  NaN
```

To get the column names, the solution can be expanded as below. We create a dict that replaces 'n' with f'Top{n}' for n from 0 to the maximum column index

```
df2 = df.groupby('Date', as_index=True)['headline'].apply(list).apply(pd.Series).reset_index()
new_col_names = {n:f'Top{n}' for n in range(len(df2.columns))}
df2.rename(columns = new_col_names, inplace = True)
df2
```

produces

```
Date    Top0    Top1    Top2
0 d1    h1      h2      h3
1 d2    h4      h5      NaN
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked well for me. Allthough I now struggle to name the columns. Since there are more than 600 columns, naming them one by one doesn't make sense. `f = lambda x: 'Headline{}'.format(int(x.split()[1])+1) if 'Unnamed' in x else x
df_test_new = df_test.rename(columns = f)` does not yield success.

Comment: I have added my suggestion on column renaming to the answer

Answer (score 1):

The following should do it:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Data example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2020-11-9', '2020-11-9', '2020-11-10', '2020-11-10', '2020-11-10'], 'Headline': ['Abbb', 'Blabla', 'cdss', 'sdd', 'asy']})
```

Use date format:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Use category that counts headlines per day:

```
df['Cat'] = df.groupby(['Date']).cumcount()
```

Work on the labels:

```
df['Top'] = 'Top'
df['Topx'] = df['Top'].astype(str)+df['Cat'].astype(str)
```

Pivot this:

```
df.pivot(index='Date', columns='Topx', values='Headline')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would start with creating a calculated ne column, which contains Top1, Top2, ... Top6

Afterwards you can pivot your dataframe based on date.

pd.pivot_table(df,index=["Name"])